# What's the best way to scrape Spectrum community data?

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I'd like to scrape Spectrum channel data. And I was thinking about using scraping tools like `Puppeteer` to login as a user and scrape a certain channel. One problem I can think of is I may not have access to the history of all chat logs before I join. How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a user on that site and then use those credentials in the scrape code.  It will have all access required.  I used HtmlAgilityPack which I find simply great for this.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/